# Mapping query to a pojo class

Tags: java, sql, jpa

This is my current query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from audit where type='SEND_DOCS_VIA_EMAIL' and user_id=:userId order by timestamp desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
AuditEntity getLatestSendEmailDateAndTime(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

AuditEntity is null , if i change to a specific type for example SELECT timestamp it will get it for me, how can i get it to return pojo that is not null

Comment: Try to use findFirst like that :

AuditEntity findFirstByUserIdOrderByTimestampDesc(Long userId);

Comment: That would work if i have a single type  but as you cna see there is different  types=SEND_DOCS_VIA_EMAIL and so on @AyoubMk